# When will we can edit ROS Wiki?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Roboticists,

As you know, ROS Wiki is still immutable but It has a lot of missing information and some outdated informations. It says this on every page:

> Note: Hi there, `<UserName>`! In an effort to combat spam, we require that
> users be added to a whitelist to gain edit permissions. To gain edit permissions for yourself, please
> comment on [**this GitHub ticket**](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/139)
> with your wiki UserName, '`<UserName>`', to be added to the whitelist. Thanks for your patience and support.

I've already commented with my Wiki Username to [there](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/139#issuecomment-178454160) 88 days ago. When will we can edit pages?

Thanks!

**EDIT: I've already changed my Username with non-spaced one before commenting on GitHub Ticket. Somehow my old Username was added to [there](http://wiki.ros.org/UserGroup). I've just reverted my user name with spaced one. And now I can Edit!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233270/when-will-we-can-edit-ros-wiki?/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

you can find the whitelist [here](http://wiki.ros.org/UserGroup).
It seems like @tfoote has already added your name. Maybe the additional whitespaces are causing the issue?

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-29**:
I've already changed my Username with non-spaced one before commenting on GitHub Ticket. Somehow my old Username was added to there. Thanks for an answer!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-04-29**:
Your original comment was

```
Please add, I'm 'Orhan Gazi Hafif'. 
Thank You!
```

Which is what was emailed to me and I added to the wiki. At some point you edited the comment to change the username to have no spaces, but editing comments does not give notifications.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-04-29**:
If you'd like to change it to the non-whitespace version (recommended) please just comment on the github ticket with your request.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-29**:
Yes Sir that's what that was. Someone said "whitespaces aren't recommended" to me, and I changed my username and comment. I wasn't knowing anything about mail. I'm commenting, Thank you!